# How get user info from Google in PHP?

Tags: php, android, google-api

I send token from Android and make this:

```
$mToken = $this->_request['token'];
                $userinfo = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $mToken;
                $json = file_get_contents($userinfo);
                $userInfoArray = json_decode($json,true);
                $googleEmail = $userInfoArray['email'];
                $tokenUserId = $userInfoArray['user_id'];
                $tokenAudience = $userInfoArray['audience'];
                $tokenIssuer = $userInfoArray['issuer'];

                if ( strcasecmp( $tokenAudience, $GOOGLE_FULL_CLIENT_ID ) != 0) {
                    error_log ( "ERROR:'" . $tokenAudience . "' did not match." );
                }
```

How can I get user info?

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: i get $userInfoArray with email, userId... I want firstName, lastName, gender and other info